# Phone numbers showing same color as header

Tags: themes, css

I had a WordPress site created by a local guy that I'm not able to to get in contact with. Currently, it appears to be working properly in all browsers except Safari on iPad.. The phone number in the header is disguised as the same color as the header color making it seem like its not there. Any tips on my how to modify this?

site is - asapdentist.com

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: post this question in stackoverflow. Because this is not the problem of wordpress

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I dont have an iPAd to hand to test this but I know that Safari likes to change phonenumbers into links which would override the current CSS which makes the text white.

You will need to change the CSS to ensure links remain white.

Try adding this CSS to your theme's style.css:

```
#main-site-caption #number { 
    color: #fff;
}
```

If you cant contact the developer you may be able to add this yourself.
You will need access to the WordPress dashboard, in the menu on the left click 'Appearance' then 'Editor' from here open the style.css file (will be listed on the right along with other theme files) and just add this to the bottom of the file.